# php code to rearrange row order in database on update of selected row

Tags: php

tablename: news

column:

```
headline, send_sub_top, sub_top_priority.
```

Below is my table structure in database.

I Only Need is when I Update Selected row from Form. It updates the `send_sub_top = "Inactive"` in database and Rearrange the order of `sub_top_priority` Column in database.

For example:

If I delete the Row 3 in database then it update `send_sub_top = "Inactive"` Of Row 3 AND `sub_top_priority = 0` Of Row 3 And then Rearrange the order of All  `sub_top_priority` Column in `Ascending` order like 1,2,3,4.

I Create code which update `send_sub_top Column = Inactive`  in database But this will not rearrange the  `sub_top_priority` order...

My code Example  -- My code only update `send_sub_top = Inactive` and keep `sub_top_priority` column order like...

After deleting 3rd row
1,2,4,5. but i need like 1,2,3,4.

```
id  headline            send_sub_top               sub_top_priority 

1    good                 Active                            1

2    Test                Active                             2

3    Nice                Active                             3 

4    Great               Active                             4

5    Demo               Active                              5
```

plz help me....thanks in advance..

below is my code...

```
<?php                  
                foreach($sub_top_select as $sub_top)
                {                       
                ?>
            <li><a href="javascript:return(0);" remove_sub_top_news="<?php echo $sub_top['id']; ?>">
                <img src="img/error.png" height="14px" width="14px" /></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
```

php code to update Inactive in database...

But i also need to Rearrange the order of All  `sub_top_priority` Column in `Ascending` order like 1,2,3,4.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['remove_sub_top_news']))
    {   
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['remove_sub_top_news'])));      
        $sql = "SELECT id,send_sub_top FROM news WHERE id='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);        
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
        mysql_query("Update news SET send_sub_top='Inactive' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['remove_sub_top_news']))));       
        if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
        {           
            $_SESSION['message'] = "News Removed From SubTop Successfully";
            header("Location:sethomepage.php");
            exit;
        }       
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First update `send_sub_top` value.

Then Select all data from the table with the condition that `set_sub_top` = 'active' and order by `sub_top_priority` ascending.

Then looping whole data of the select query update the `sub_top_priority` by increment of 1.

NB : This method is good if there is not much data in table.

Comment: but my database has lakh of records.plz suggest code

Comment: why you need to reorder the data in the database. Keep it as it is in the database and just tackle at the time of view.